# checking for variable changes within a specified amount of time?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to check for variable changes within a specified amount of time. For example I got a variable:
int downloadProgress = 0;

and I got some code which downloads a file and the var downloadProgress is being update to 1..2.3....5.6..7. until ..100 (download finishes).

Now I want to have a thread like the following:

```
Runnable checkNet = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        // check variable changes
    }
};
```

that checks for changes in the variable downloadProgress within a specified amount of time say 20 seconds. If the variable doesn't change for at least 20 seconds than I want to do something!

How could I utilize a timer to do this within a thread!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use timer: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html  In this case you will not need a thread, because Timer imlies a thread

Here is example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
tv = new TextView(this);
this.setContentView(tv);

MyCount counter = new MyCount(5000,1000);
counter.start();
}

public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
}
@Override
public void onFinish() {
tv.setText(”done!”);
}
@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
tv.setText(”Left: ” + millisUntilFinished/1000);
}
}

}
```

Source: http://dewful.com/?p=3

Comment: so I would use the method onTick to check for variable changes right ?